# Override javascript

Tags: javascript

[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4afPF.png)

when I hit the button on the top left on https://real-one.shifaul.repl.co/, nothing happens except the text changing to "to daily"
but what I want it is when I hit the button , it will change my javascript 
the line that is running now (highlighted in blue) will stop working, and the line that is in the comment will start working, when I hit again it gets back to normal. it will go on forever

```
fetchTexts().then(([enQuotes, bnQuotes]) => {

  const totalQuotes = enQuotes.length;

  function getQuote() {

    const pickedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalQuotes);
    
    //const now = new Date(); const days = Math.floor(now/1000/60/60/24); const pickedIndex = days % totalQuotes

    const newImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*6); document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${newImageIndex}.jpg)`;

    document.querySelector("#text1").innerText = enQuotes[pickedIndex];
    document.querySelector("#text2").innerText = bnQuotes[pickedIndex];
  }

  getQuote(0); 
setInterval(function() {
  getQuote()
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

full code: https://replit.com/join/xedbtvda-shifaul

Comment: You mean toggle between `now` and `newImageIndex`?

Comment: just use `flag` and toggle it according to the value of `flag`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that based on your code, you can do that:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1")

const now = new Date(); 
const days = Math.floor(now/1000/60/60/24); 
    
const pickedIndex =  elem.value === 'On refresh'       
  ? Math.floor(Math.random() * totalQuotes) 
  : days % totalQuotes
```

This worked for me (I tested by lowering the value of getQuotes interval)

Comment: yes, but there is a problem, when I refresh it goes back to default, it doesn't stay saved

Comment: what do you mean by "it doe not stay saved" I think either it is saved, or it is not saved :)

Comment: After I change it to "on daily" when I refresh the page, the page goes back to default, it doesn't stay saved it goes back to "on refresh", 
Is it to do anything with localStorage? or somethings wrong?
website:https://real-one.shifaul.repl.co/

Comment: How did you write the code on that page in the first place?